# Rails 5: validation of acceptance for a checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a sign-up form with some nested fields, and inside this form I have added a checkbox for the terms of service.

I'm trying to validate when the checkbox is checked or not and return an error if not.

```
 validates_acceptance_of :agreement, :allow_nil => true, :accept => true, :on => :create
```

I do have a boolean column that is set to default inside the accounts table.

```
add_column :accounts, :agreement, :boolean, default: false
```

Also, I have added the `:agreement` to the permitted controller params.

This is the form:

```
   <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <div class="centerList">
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <%= devise_error_messages! %></div>
    </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "email", :class=>"form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
        <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "password", autocomplete: "off", :class=>"form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "confirm password", autocomplete: "off", :class=>"form-control"  %>
      </div>

      <%= f.fields_for :account do |form| %>


      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
        <%= form.text_field :street, placeholder: "street", :class=>"form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
        <%= form.text_field :city, placeholder: "city", :class=>"form-control"  %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
        <%= form.text_field :state, placeholder: "state", :class=>"form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
        <%= form.text_field :zip_code, placeholder: "zip code", :class=>"form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="asterisk_input"></span>
        <%= form.country_select :country, ["US"], {}, { :class => "form-control", :id=>"sign-frm-input" } %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.check_box :agreement %> I agree to the <%= link_to 'Terms', term_path(:id=>1) %>.
      </div>

<% end %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class=>'btn btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>
```

But it returns the form error `agreement must be accepted` even if I do accept it. Any ideas what I might be missing ohere!

Answer (score 9):

Try: `validates :agreement, acceptance: {accept: true} , on: :create, 
allow_nil: false`

You don't want to `:allow_nil => true` if you're validating for acceptance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @tmee...It's returning a form error `agreement must be accepted`

Comment: @Theopap stick `raise params.inspect` in your controller action to double check `:agreement` is in your `:account` hash

Answer (score 2):

You can change your model validations and test it.

```
validates :agreement, inclusion: {in: [true]}
```

or you can use other validation

```
validates :agreement, acceptance: { accept: true }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @Sahidur Rahman Suman both of them return a form error... first one: agreement is not included in the list and second one agreement must be accepted